# pronunciation of L.A (Los Angeles)

Tags: pronunciation

how should i pronounce L.A. in normal speech?

el lay

or

el ay

or something else

does the L spill over to the A?

Comment: More technically, for any answerers, is there a glottal stop after the 'l' or not?

Answer (score 1):

***el-ay*** or

***e-lay***.

Never *el-lay*.

Answer (score 0):

In "normal" speech you would, with all probability, say either "elay" "el ay".

In normal discourse you do not often make a distinction between words, so the sounds of two different words (letters in this case) seem to meld together and form "one word". Or you could have a glottal stop between words/sounds as Mitch pointed out in the comments.